# Wordpress Template. Display contents of a Text Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a wordpress template.

I have added some HTML into a Text widget and saved it.

Is there a way to add some code into my template so I can get that widget to be displayed?

Is this possible instead of having to enter the html code directly into my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Text widget will be inside of a sidebar.  So if you have a sidebar called "left-sidebar", you can use code like this in your template.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
  <ul id="sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now all the widgets you put in left-sidebar will be included in that template automatically.

There's more information about dynamic_sidebar here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

Note that you can also create new sidebars using register_sidebar in your functions.php, so if you want to use different sidebars in different templates you can.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is infact it's very simple, you have to create a sidebar for where you wan that widget to go. In your main php file or wherever you want that widget to appear you can add the following code:

```html
 <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
    || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar1') ) : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Then you would also have to declare that sidebar within the functions.php file like so:

```html
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'sidebar1',
'before_widget' => '',
'after_widget' => '',
'before_title' => '',
'after_title' => '',
));
```

and you can have as many sidebars that you want, just give them a different name like sidebar2 etc..

Comment: OK, I've added this code to my template and function.php and opened the widgets area but cannot see any sidebars there. I'm I forgetting something?

Comment: it's hard to say without fully seeing your code, maybe you have like an index.php, page.php, post.php and maybe your looking at the wrong category of page?

Comment: I generally just use a free program on http://www.wpsiteconvertor.com/ to convert my html site to wordpress, this code I got out of their, and it worked well on my site

Comment: try maybe pasting the code from your main page like on header.php and seeing if that works? becuase that should work sitewide if at all.

Comment: Yes, it should say sidebar1 in that widget area, so it seems it may not be properly set up in the functions.php file

Comment: I just pasted the code into the bottom of function.php and not into the init part. Basically wrong place. Thanks :)